# Captializing S in stylesheet mentioned in rel attribute

Tags: css, html, tags

After a deep search, there is something to be known by me which puts me to think a lot and couldn't get the idea of the purpose that it serves. Which is capitalizing the **S** in **stylesheet** for `rel` attribute value.

what is the difference between,

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/widgets/some.css">`

and

`<link rel="Stylesheet" href="/css/widgets/some.css">`

what purpose does it serves? An on-shore 15years experienced web application head is insisting to do this. Please explain and make me understand.

Comment: _"Link types are always ASCII case-insensitive, and must be compared as such."_ See: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#linkTypes Tell him to get back in his box. His stylistic preferences shouldn't no more be imposed on you than yours on him.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, as [link types are case insensitive](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/links.html#allowed-keywords-and-their-meanings). I am guessing that your colleague prefers them that way for some reason.